# VeriSign Time Stamping Services Signer G2 revocation error

Tags: windows, certificate, digital-signature, verisign, timestamping

after recent windows updates (Windows 7) - I'm getting error when verifying digital signature on some files.
The verification fails for Countersignature certificate:
[image]

Anyone has the same issue? Or maybe found a resolution?

Thanks,
Zahar

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a connectivity issue - the CRL for some certificate can not be downloaded by he client. You need to inspect the certificates on the screenshot, check their properties and find CRL Distribution Point extension there. It's likely that you will find http://crl.verisign.com/tss-ca.crl there. Then you need to check if you can connect to this URL from the browser. If you can't, then the problem is either in the firewall or in some other network component.